# Eclipse program not working

Tags: eclipse

Hello I'm creating an Android project using Eclipse the emulator is very slow I tried using the emulator through my phone but it still wont work I have a Kyocera Event and  android 4.0
software anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this problem so I can run the emulator through my phone?

Answer (score 3):

Try to use HAXM if you have an Intel processor and a different image of the system rather than ARM. I had similar problem with debugging using my tablet, I would highly recommend HAXM.

Answer (score 1):

Did you enable USB Debugging in your phone settings? And check SDK Manager - Extra - Google USB Driver

Answer (score 0):

I have been using real devices to test my apps, and if you dont know, your device might not be recognized by your IDE even though it is picked up by your computer. The solution, first, click http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html
 scroll down to the bottom, locate the manufaturer of your phone and download the appropriate driver for your device, install it, then, you need to open the "SDK Manager" to download the system images for the platforms you want to test against, you might need to download the "Google USB Driver" in the "Extras" section in "SDK Manager". Or if you want an emulator that is as fast as a real device, consider "Geny Motion", pretty easy to install. You can search for "Geny Motion" through google, shoule be able to see it the first result. Hope this helps.